# Getting ReferenceError: $ is not defined in angularJS directive on Plunker but not on Fiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement Collapse-expand behavior of div using angular JS. I found out [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paragdiwan/9qJ2g/8/) which is working perfectly fine but when I try this from [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9PKIuqmN0l8eBMvpmVcW?p=preview), its throwing

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at link (http://run.plnkr.co/IckVASWWji617HjT/script.js:11:13)
```

which is

```
$(element).click( function() {  // in script.js
```

How come its working on Fiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` usually refers to `jQuery` and in this case it does.

Add `jQuery` to your plunker by selecting "Find and Add external libraries" in the right sidebar, searching for jquery, and adding it.

Comment: But jquery hasn't been included in fiddle. Right?

Comment: Yes, it has. If you click on the button "JavaScript" (in the bottom-left frame) you can see that jQuery 2.0.2 is included in the fiddle

Comment: They changed it a few months back. Imho it was easier to find before, but you could say that now it's more organized